# Find Entries based on Field Values

Tags: entries, field, datetime, query

I have a set of events I want to query based on user-input date times.
How do I achieve something like this?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').minScheduleDate('>=', 'now').maxScheduleDate('<=', 'now') %}
```

Where `maxScheduleDate` is a field for user to input date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this link solves your issue.
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/date-time-fields.html#settings

Comment: What if the field isn't a datetime field?

Comment: As long as it is not an element field like matrix, category, asset, entry. You can apply something similar to it.